# My CollectionView is loading to the middle of the loaded posts on launch, can I make it load at the top instead?

Tags: android, maui

I'm not sure why my CollectionView seems to be loading into the middle (or bottom?) of the first set of results, and I'm wondering if there is something I'm missing to make it load at the top.  I found InitialScrollIndex, but it seems that is Xamarin only and not available in .NET MAUI.  Is there anything to replace that?  The only other thing I can find is to use `ScrollTo(0)`, but that still loads to the middle and then there is a visual jump to the top.

Comment: Show me the XAML. (Code wont hurt also)

Comment: Okay I feel like a dummy now, but it turns out it was because I forgot that I had added a Footer on my collectionview a while back, it never showed up and I moved on to something else.  So, kind of a side-question here: Will a footer never show up on a CollectionView that always loads more posts?  I kind of expected it to just show up at the bottom of the screen on top of everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will a footer never show up on a CollectionView that always loads more posts? I kind of expected it to just show up at the bottom of the screen on top of everything.

Take buttons as an example, button is inside the footer. You mean that you want to keep button constantly visible at the bottom of the screen no matter how many items CollectionView has? If so, Footer can't do it. You can see its [definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#headers-and-footers):

> `Footer`, of type `object`, specifies the string, binding, or view that will be displayed at the end of the list.

However, you can put button out of footer like this:

```xml
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <CollectionView x:Name="list"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <CollectionView.Footer>
                <Button Text="click" x:Name="btn1" />
            </CollectionView.Footer>
        </CollectionView>
        <Button Text="click" x:Name="btn2" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

And here is the [effect](https://imgur.com/a/15QQHHY).